# Python merging multiple JSON into one JSON without result merged in list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I was trying to merge multiple JSON files into one JSON files

if file1.json has dict like

{"cars": 1, "houses": 2, "schools": 3, "stores": 4}

and file2.json has dict like

{"Pens": 1, "Pencils": 2, "Paper": 3}

The result I am looking for is file3.json

{"cars": 1, "houses": 2, "schools": 3, "stores": 4, "Pens": 1, "Pencils": 2, "Paper": 3}

However I got [{"cars": 1, "houses": 2, "schools": 3, "stores": 4, "Pens": 1, "Pencils": 2, "Paper": 3}] with the bracket at the start and the end

here is my code

```
glob_data=[]
for file in p_test:
    with open(file) as infile:
        glob_data.append(json.load(infile))
        # print(glob_data)
with open(path, "w") as data:
    json.dump(glob_data, data)

with open(path,encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

how can I fix my code so I can combine them not in list data type?
thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, your code SPECIFICALLY creates `glob_data` as a list.  If you didn't want a list, why did you do that?

Comment: Hi I just couldn't find other way to combine those muiltiple json files into one beside that. Would you recommend other method?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a dictionary and update it:

```
data={}
for file in p_test:
    with open(file) as infile:
        data.update(json.load(infile))
with open(path, "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)

with open(path,encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Comment: thanks! i will try them. would this work on multiple json as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple JSON"?

Comment: i.e) if I run this script, i have result with only file2 merged with empty dict

Comment: Then you have typed it incorrectly.  This works -- I tried it before I posted it.